# Show uploading form only if video or image selected from dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have very simple form. I have one dropdown menu where default is text selected. I want show file uploading box only if we select image or video from dropdown menu. Its HTML/PHP page. I have tried to put javascript in my body tag but its not working.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $('#faq_type').on('change', function () {
         $("#upload").css('display', (this.value == '1' || this.value == '2') ? 'block' : 
          'none');
       }); 
        </script>
```

my dropdown form is like this

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                  <select name="faq_type" id="faq_type" class="select2" required>
                      <option value="0" <?php if($row['type'] == "0") echo "selected"; ?>>Text</option>
                      <option value="1" <?php if($row['type'] == "1") echo "selected"; ?>>Image</option>
                      <option value="2" <?php if($row['type'] == "2") echo "selected"; ?>>Video</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
```

My full page is like this

```
<?php include("includes/header.php");

    require("includes/function.php");
    require("language/language.php");
    require_once("thumbnail_images.class.php");


    if(isset($_POST['submit']) and isset($_GET['add']))
        {

             $picture_name=rand(0,99999)."_".$_FILES['picture_name']['name'];
             $pic1=$_FILES['picture_name']['tmp_name'];


             $tpath1='images/'.$picture_name; 
             copy($pic1,$tpath1);

             $thumbpath='images/thumbs/'.$picture_name;

                $obj_img = new thumbnail_images();
                $obj_img->PathImgOld = $tpath1;
                $obj_img->PathImgNew =$thumbpath;
                $obj_img->NewWidth = 100;
                $obj_img->NewHeight = 100;
                if (!$obj_img->create_thumbnail_images()) 
                  {
                    echo $_SESSION['msg']="Thumbnail not created... please upload image again";

                    exit;
                  }

            $data = array(
                    'question'  =>  $_POST['question'],
                    'answer'  =>  $_POST['answer'],
                    'type'  =>  $_POST['faq_type'],
                   'picture_name'  =>  $picture_name
                    );      

            $qry = Insert('faq',$data);         

            $_SESSION['msg']="10";

            header( "Location:faq.php");
            exit;   



        }   
    if(isset($_GET['faq_id']))
    {

            $qry="SELECT * FROM faq where id ='".$_GET['faq_id']."'";
            $result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$qry);
            $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit']) and isset($_POST['faq_id']))
    {

         if($_FILES['picture_name']['name']!="")
         {      


                $img_res=mysqli_query($mysqli,'SELECT * FROM faq WHERE id='.$_GET['faq_id'].'');
                $img_res_row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($img_res);


                if($img_res_row['picture_name']!="")
                {
                    unlink('images/thumbs/'.$img_res_row['picture_name']);
                    unlink('images/'.$img_res_row['picture_name']);
                 }

                   $picture_name=rand(0,99999)."_".$_FILES['picture_name']['name'];
                   $pic1=$_FILES['picture_name']['tmp_name'];
                   $tpath1='images/'.$picture_name;

                    copy($pic1,$tpath1);

                    $thumbpath='images/thumbs/'.$picture_name;

                    $obj_img = new thumbnail_images();
                    $obj_img->PathImgOld = $tpath1;
                    $obj_img->PathImgNew =$thumbpath;
                    $obj_img->NewWidth = 100;
                    $obj_img->NewHeight = 100;
                    if (!$obj_img->create_thumbnail_images()) 
                      {
                        echo $_SESSION['msg']="Thumbnail not created... please upload image again";
                        exit;
                      }

                    $data = array(
                        'question'  =>  $_POST['question'],
                        'answer'  =>  $_POST['answer'],
                        'type'  =>  $_POST['faq_type'],
                        'picture_name'  =>  $picture_name
                        );

                    $faq_edit=Update('faq', $data, "WHERE id = '".$_POST['faq_id']."'");

         }
         else
         {

                     $data = array(
                      'question'  =>  $_POST['question'],
                        'answer'  =>  $_POST['answer'],
                        'type'  =>  $_POST['faq_type']
                        );  

                     $faq_edit=Update('faq', $data, "WHERE id = '".$_POST['faq_id']."'");

         }

            if ($faq_edit > 0)
            { 

                        $_SESSION['msg']="11"; 
                        header( "Location:add_faq.php?faq_id=".$_POST['faq_id']);
                        exit;

            }
    }


?>



<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>



<body>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $('#faq_type').on('change', function () {
         $("#upload").css('display', (this.value == '1' || this.value == '2') ? 'block' : 
          'none');
       }); 
        </script>

       <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="page_title_block">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
              <div class="page_title">Add FAQ</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <div class="card-body mrg_bottom">
            <form class="form form-horizontal" action="" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkValidation(this);">
              <input  type="hidden" name="faq_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['faq_id'];?>" />
              <div class="section">
                <div class="section-body">

                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">FAQ Type :-</label>
                <?php if(isset($_GET['faq_id'])) {?>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <select name="faq_type" id="faq_type" class="select2" required>
                      <option value="0" <?php if($row['type'] == "0") echo "selected"; ?>>Text</option>
                      <option value="1" <?php if($row['type'] == "1") echo "selected"; ?>>Image</option>
                      <option value="2" <?php if($row['type'] == "2") echo "selected"; ?>>Video</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                 <?php } else {?>
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                      <select name="faq_type" id="faq_type" class="select2" required>
                          <option value="0">Text</option>
                          <option value="1">Image</option>
                          <option value="2">Video</option>
                      </select>
                 </div>
                 <?php }?>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group" id="upload" style="display: none">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Select File :-</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="fileupload_block" >
                        <input type="file" name="picture_name" value="fileupload" id="fileupload">
                        <?php if(isset($_GET['faq_id']) and $row['picture_name']!="") {?>
                              <div class="fileupload_img"><img type="image" src="images/<?php echo $row['picture_name'];?>" alt="category image" /></div>
                            <?php } else {?>
                              <div class="fileupload_img"><img type="image" src="assets/images/add-image.png" alt="category image" /></div>
                            <?php }?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <label class="control-label">Question :-</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                     <textarea name="question" id="question" rows="1" class="form-control" ><?php if(isset($_GET['faq_id'])){echo $row['question'];}?></textarea> 
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <label class="control-label">Answer:-</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                     <textarea name="answer" id="answer" rows="1" class="form-control" data-emojiable="true"><?php if(isset($_GET['faq_id'])){echo $row['answer'];}?></textarea> 
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">&nbsp;</div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
                      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<?php include("includes/footer.php");?>
```

Let me know if someone can correct, whats wrong in this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Try placing the script tags at the bottom of the body, instead of the top. I think it's possible you're attaching events to elements that do not yet exist in the DOM.

Comment: I have tried to put in bottom, head and in body but same result, its not changing anything

Comment: Try this in your script.
`$("#upload").css('display', ( $(this).value == '1' || $(this).value == '2') ? 'block' : 'none');`